# CSS & JS Not Loading in Template in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and want to load a template. However, when I load it only HTML-based data shows and CSS/JS files are not loading. All of my CSS and JS files are in the /public folder. Is there any solution to this problem?

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/bootstrap.min') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/bootstrap-responsive.min') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/fullcalendar') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/matrix-style') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/matrix-media') }}" />
<link href="font-awesome/{{ asset('css/fonts/backend_fonts/css/fonts-awesome.css') }}" 
  rel="stylesheet" />
```

**JS**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/backend_js/excanvas.min.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/backend_js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/backend_js/jquery.ui.custom.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/backend_js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/backend_js/jquery.flot.min.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/backend_js/jquery.flot.resize.min.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/backend_js/jquery.peity.min.js') }}"></script>
```

[Here](http://imageshack.com/i/pmpvdy1ip) is the link of a screenshot of my folder.

Here are the links which are showing in developer mode in Google Chrome.

```
href="http://localhost/laravel/ecom2/public/css/backend_css/bootstrap.min"
href="http://localhost/laravel/ecom2/public/css/backend_css/bootstrap-responsive.min"
href="http://localhost/laravel/ecom2/public/css/backend_css/fullcalendar"
src="http://localhost/laravel/ecom2/public/js/backend_js/matrix.interface.js"
src="http://localhost/laravel/ecom2/public/js/backend_js/matrix.chat.js"
src="http://localhost/laravel/ecom2/public/js/backend_js/jquery.validate.js"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/bootstrap.min') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/bootstrap-responsive.min') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/fullcalendar') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/matrix-style') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/matrix-media') }}" />
```

There is an mistake here. Your `css` file must end by `.css` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```

And check your `js` file too

Answer (score 0):

**Your css, js path is not valid right now**

you didn't attached the `extensions` in your css,js files

also, you should run your project with artisan

```
php artisan serve
```

then goto `localhost:8000`

Comment: still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
URL::asset(‘your resource here’)
```

Instead of

```
asset(‘your resource here’)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error, use proper css extensions

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend_css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you run

```
 php artisan serve
```

and fix your .css extension